# Undefined behaviour with #define in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, undefined-behavior

I've got a define in C, looks like this

```
#define ROW_SIZE ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE
```

It evaluates to 293 
Then I do this

```
uint32_t num_rows = pager->file_length / ROW_SIZE;
```

`pager->file_length` is 0 for sure
The result of `num_rows` is 289. Even `0 / ROW_SIZE` evaluates to 289.

Why is the answer to expression wrong?

Comment: `#define ROW_SIZE ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE` -> `#define (ROW_SIZE ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE)`

Comment: This is a very common FAQ. Any beginner-level C programming book will explain how to write proper macros, in the pre-processor chapter. It will dead certain mention this particular bug with operator precedence and lack of proper parenthesis. So go read that chapter.

Comment: Anyone know of a canonical duplicate for this? We need one!

Comment: Always put parenthesis when defining a macro

Comment: @Lundin How about this one:  [Is there a good reason for always enclosing a define in parentheses in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081479/is-there-a-good-reason-for-always-enclosing-a-define-in-parentheses-in-c)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Seems mostly focused on if parenthesis is still needed even though there's just one pre-processor token. I think we need something more basic to use as canonical dupe.

Comment: @Lundin Unfortunately, we killed *StackOverflow Documentation*... It would be useful in such cases

Comment: @KyrSt No, one of many reasons why we killed it because it was partially filled with crap, written by confused beginners. For a high quality FAQ, there's the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), which is maintained and only points at high quality Q&A canonical dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that

```
uint32_t num_rows = pager->file_length / ROW_SIZE;
```

is expanded into

```
uint32_t num_rows = pager->file_length / ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE;
```

so num_rows is evaluates to `0 + ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE`, which is not a zero. Consider adding parentheses to your define:

```
#define ROW_SIZE (ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Macro expansion is token-based replacement. In other words,

```
pager->file_length / ROW_SIZE
```

expands to

```
pager->file_length / ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE
```

I believe you agree the above is not necessarily zero, especially if `USERNAME_SIZE` or `EMAIL_SIZE` are nonzero.

To solve this, put parentheses around the expression in the macro definition:

```
#define ROW_SIZE (ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be written like this:

```
#define ROW_SIZE (ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that preprocessor macros are basically query-replaced in the source code.

If you have e.g.

```
uint32_t num_rows = pager->file_length / ROW_SIZE;
```

what the compiler sees after preprocessing is

```
uint32_t num_rows = pager->file_length / ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE;
```

Due to the normal [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) that is equal to

```
uint32_t num_rows = (pager->file_length / ID_SIZE) + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE;
```

which of course is not what you expect or want. Therefore it's important to always use extra parentheses in macros, as in

```
#define ROW_SIZE (ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE)
```