# Why use parenthesis on a single value in macro definition?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I can make sense of this:

```
#define ADD( f1, f2 ) ( (f1) + (f2) )
```

And I guess you could write something like

```
#define TWO (1+1)
```

to avoid precedence issues.

But why do I often see something like that:

```
#define TCS34725_ADDRESS (0x29)
```

Is there any point in having those parenthesis around a single value?

Comment: The only point is consistency (and consistency is good -- except perhaps in this case).

Comment: BTW, I'd do `#define ADD(f1, f2) ((f1) + (f2))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good reason for always enclosing a define in parentheses in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081479/is-there-a-good-reason-for-always-enclosing-a-define-in-parentheses-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `0x29` and `(0x29)` are primary expressions, so the only noticeable difference occurs when converted to string literals by macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A1 (0x29)
#define A2 0x29

#define MKSTR_(x) #x
#define MKSTR(x) MKSTR_(x)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n%s\n", MKSTR(A1), MKSTR(A2));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(0x29)
0x29
```

If you only care about the numeric value, then parentheses around constants in the macro replacement text are superfluous and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the macro is used. In some cases it makes sense

```
#define FOO1( f1, f2 ) ( f1 * f2 )
#define FOO1( f1, f2 ) ( (f1) * (f2) ) // recommended
```

give very different results when fed with

```
FOO1( 12+12, 13+12)
```

In the case of (0x29) it depends how it is used.

Comment: You should point out that `#define FOO1( f1, f2 ) ( (f1) * (f2) )` is the only correct way

Comment: thanks. would you mind adding an example where it would make sense to have `(0x29)` instead of `0x29` because that's my question. "it depends" doesn't help me too much :)